# My document will not compile with this table in it

Tags: tables, compiling

I've had a problem with compiling my document with this table in it:

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{Porovnanie priemerných hodnôt maxím v jednotlivých oblastiach buniek oboma metódami generovania lokalizačných máp a typmi binárnych masiek pri klasifikácii bunkovej línie.}
\begin{tabular}{c|cc|cc}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Grad-Cam}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Oklúzia}} \\ \cline{2-5} 
\textbf{Oblasť buniek} & manuálne masky & automatické masky & manuálne masky & automatické masky \\ \hline
Cytoplazma & 0,95 & 0,98 & 0,88 & 0,92 \\
Jadrá bez jadierok & 0,81 & 0,85 & 0,71 & 0,64 \\
Jadierka & 0,81 & 0,76 & 0,71 & 0,73
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:table4}
\end{table}
```

I've generated it using a https://www.tablesgenerator.com editor and up until this point, there have been no issues with other tables. I don't get any error messages, it just keeps compiling forever.
Sorry that the content is not in English.
Thanks for your help!

**Edit:**
Problem solved. I removed the `\cline{2-5}` at the end of the first row and shortened some elements. Maybe the maximum set width of the document just wasn't enough.

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{Porovnanie priemerných hodnôt maxím v jednotlivých oblastiach buniek oboma metódami generovania lokalizačných máp a typmi binárnych masiek pri klasifikácii bunkovej línie.}
\begin{tabular}{c|cc|cc}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Grad-Cam}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Oklúzia}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Oblasť buniek} & manuálne & automatické & manuálne & automatické \\ \hline
Cytoplazma & 0,95 & 0,98 & 0,88 & 0,92 \\
Jadrá bez jadierok & 0,81 & 0,85 & 0,88 & 0,92 \\
Jadierka & 0,81 & 0,76 & 0,71 & 0,73 \\
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:table4}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Your code, [wrapped inside a minimal document](https://pastebin.com/raw/b8YHkwUH), compiles without problem. So your issue is elsewhere. Can you provide a complete, minimal document that replicates your issue?

Comment: @wipet Dude, he said that it just loops forever and that is why he cannot extract error messages. I guess it's latexmk, sometimes it does loop forever.

Answer (score 1):

We need to see the full document, because your example actually works:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, letterpaper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{slovak}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{caption}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\KOMAoptions{BCOR = 8.25mm, DIV = 16}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \caption{Porovnanie priemerných hodnôt maxím v jednotlivých oblastiach buniek oboma metódami generovania lokalizačných máp a typmi binárnych masiek pri klasifikácii bunkovej línie.}
    \begin{tabular}{c|cc|cc}
     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Grad-Cam}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Oklúzia}} \\ \cline{2-5}
    \textbf{Oblasť buniek} & manuálne masky & automatické masky & manuálne masky & automatické masky \\ \hline
    Cytoplazma & 0,95 & 0,98 & 0,88 & 0,92 \\
    Jadrá bez jadierok & 0,81 & 0,85 & 0,71 & 0,64 \\
    Jadierka & 0,81 & 0,76 & 0,71 & 0,73
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:table4}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]